# Lua - calling a function with more params that defined

Tags: function, parameters, lua

for some reason, I need to get understand an uncommented chunk of lua code. I am not working in Lua, but I am able to understand it enough based on knowledge multiple other languages. One thing surprised me, though, and I do not know how to understand it (as I never encountered that in other languages):

There is a function defined, with one param:

```
function dosomething(a) 
  ...
end
```

There is no other definition of that function. And the function is called only at one spot of the program - with two params:

```
  dosomething(a, b)
```

Both by context and by the name, the first parameter of the call is trully intended to be the first parameter by the function. Now, what about the other parameter? Tried to google, but no luck so far...

Thanks for help.

Comment: Lua allows it, but the `b` does nothing.

Comment: Thanks. I supposed this might be the answer, but was reluctant to believe it :)

Answer (score 3):

Any extra arguments are ignored.

Any missing arguments are given the value nil.

Answer (score 3):

> Tried to google, but no luck so far...

Try the Lua manual next time.

From [Lua 5.4 Reference Manual 3.4.11 - Function Definitions](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.11)

> Parameters act as local variables that are initialized with the
> argument values:
>
> parlist ::= namelist [‘,’ ‘...’] | ‘...’ When a Lua function is
> called, it adjusts its list of arguments to the length of its list of
> parameters, unless the function is a vararg function, which is
> indicated by three dots ('...') at the end of its parameter list.

So a function defined as

```
function dosomething(a) end
```

has a single parameter `a`.

Called as `dosomething(c, d)` Lua will first evaluate the argument list. So if `d` were a function it would be called and replaced by its return values.

Then an assignment will happen. As for all assignments the value list will be adjusted to the number of variables. `d` will be ignored which leaves you with `a = c`.

Refer to [3.3.3 Assignment](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.3.3)

> Lua allows multiple assignments. Therefore, the syntax for assignment
> defines a list of variables on the left side and a list of expressions
> on the right side. The elements in both lists are separated by commas:
>
> stat ::= varlist ‘=’ explist    varlist ::= var {‘,’ var}   explist ::=
> exp {‘,’ exp} Expressions are discussed in §3.4.
>
> Before the assignment, the list of values is adjusted to the length of
> the list of variables. If there are more values than needed, the
> excess values are thrown away. If there are fewer values than needed,
> the list is extended with nil's.

so `a = b, c` becomes `a = b` and `a, b = c` becomes `a, b = c, nil`